# Select & Export-CSV Not saving all data

Tags: powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' | ForEach {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EmpID)'" -Properties Name, EmployeeID, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, Fax |
    Select Name, EmployeeID, EmailAddress, OfficePhone, Fax | 
    Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test3.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I'm trying to save multiple pieces of User info, but it only saves one User.

[image: Exported CSV]

Comment: `Export-Csv` has to be outside the `ForEach-Object` loop to receive all objects coming from the pipeline

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon omg thank you!
I'm new to PowerShell and this has been stressing me for half the day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain the issue, the CSV is being overwritten per found user on your loop. `Get-ADUser` passes the queried AD object to `Select-Object` which filters the object's properties to construct a new object and then passes this new object to `Export-Csv` which writes the object to a file as CSV, this process is being repeated per loop iteration (per line of your CSV).

The immediate fix would be to add `-Append` to `Export-Csv` so instead of overwriting the file, it appends new lines however this is very inefficient. `Export-Csv` is designed to receive all objects coming from the pipeline to then write all of them at once, hence the way to go is to have it as the last statement:

```
$properties = 'Name', 'EmployeeID', 'EmailAddress', 'OfficePhone', 'Fax'
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$($_.EmpID)'" -Properties $properties
} | Select-Object $properties | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test3.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```